# Google Maps API "setVisible is not a function" Error

Tags: javascript, api, maps

I have a issue with my goole maps api. I get the data through json, which is working perfectly, but the filter is not working although it should. It seems like the arrays are nto being read as marker objects.

Any help would be really apprechiated, as I am not a master at web developing.

Here is my Javascript:

```js
var map;
var locations = [];

function initMap() {
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    $.getJSON("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/CHANGEDFORSECURITYREASONS/values/Sheet1!A2:N?key=CHANGEDFORSECURITYREASONS", function(data) {


        $(data.values).each(function() {
          var location = {};
            location.title = this[0];
            location.latitude = parseFloat(this[2]);
            location.longitude = parseFloat(this[3]);
            location.plz = this[4];
            location.address = this[7];
            location.cat = this[13];
            location.category = this[13];

            locations.push(location);
        });

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0)
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        setLocations(map, locations);
    });
}

function setLocations(map, locations) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "Content String"
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var new_marker = createMarker(map, locations[i], infowindow);
        bounds.extend(new_marker.position);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function createMarker(map, location, infowindow) {


    var position = {
        lat: parseFloat(location.latitude),
        lng: parseFloat(location.longitude)
    };
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: location.title,
        category: location.category,
    });

function filterMarkersByCategory(category) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var marker = locations[i];

        // If is same category or category not picked
        var visible = marker.category == category || category.length === 0;
        marker.setVisible(visible);
    }

}
```

```css
        #map {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <select onchange="filterMarkersByCategory(this.value)">
        <option value="">Please select a category</option>
        <option value="Kaufland">Kaufland</option>
        <option value="Edeka">Edeka</option>
        <option value="car">Car dealers</option>
    </select>
 
<div id="map" style="">      
</div>
```

Comment: `filterMarkersByCategory` method should be outside of  `createMarker` method; and closing bracket is missing

Comment: `createMarker()` should return marker

Comment: @RahulKumar the Brackets are fine, maybe there was an error copy pasting

Comment: what error you are getting?